# excel - return the minimum value in range and also the cell colour (format)

Tags: excel

I have a range of discrete cells with different values and cell colours, e.g. a1=3 (in blue), d1=1 (in red), g1=2 (in green) and there is a formula in cell j1=min(a1,d1,g1) that it returns the value of d1 (1).

How can I have cell j1 also showing the same cell colour (or more advanced, all the formats including font, alignment, border, etc.) as the minimum cell, i.e. cell j1 to be also in red (and also other formats) as cell d1?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried the CELL function?

Comment: @toucansame Cell function do not return color. It returns 0 or 1 if cell is formatted to color. To return color it need vba `UDF`.

Comment: @harun24hr thanks for clarification. A quick search turned up the following: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136127/vba-function-that-returns-color-rbg-code-of-a-referenced-cell

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes close is using conditional formatting. But then you have to define the colours in 2 places (in the cells A1,D1 and G1 and in J1).
Create 3 conditional formatting rules for cell j1:

```
=IF(MIN(A1,D1,G1)=A1,TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(MIN(A1,D1,G1)=D1,TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(MIN(A1,D1,G1)=G1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will apply this solution for the moment (I have 7 discrete values).

Answer (score 0):

I found this code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136127/vba-function-that-returns-color-rbg-code-of-a-referenced-cell). Credit to @thunderframe. There are some limitations however:
**1** Formulas must be refreshed if changes are made to the cell color (press `F9` to accomplish this). **2** VBA script must be installed in the workbook, it cannot be used if it's stored in a `PERSONAL` workbook (as discussed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566)). **3** It does not work to identify colors defined in conditional formatting.

```
 Public Function ColorCode(Reference As Range) As Variant
   Application.Volatile
' Function to return RGB code of a single cell when referenced

Dim RGBColor As Long

Dim Red As Long, Green As Long, Blue As Long

RGBColor = Reference.Interior.Color

    Red = &HFF& And RGBColor

    Green = (&HFF00& And RGBColor) \ 256

    Blue = (&HFF0000 And RGBColor) \ 65536

ColorCode = Red & "/" & Green & "/" & Blue

End Function
```